# Force HTTP (no SSL) on a single page in a site where all pages are forced HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess

I know that there exists several posts asking about the exact same thing. I asked the same question again, since I've read each and every one of them, and tried the solutions. Maybe they worked for the O.Ps'es codes, but unfortunately didn't work for mine.

I **really** need to disable HTTPS on a single PHP page called `play.php`, so that the page is accessible via direct HTTP, or redirect to HTTP if directly requested via HTTPS.

I need to change `https://example.com/play/blabla` to `http://example.com/play/blabla`, while the rest of the site is forced HTTPS.

Here is my full .htaccess  code:-

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*********"

ErrorDocument 404 /pagenotfound.php
ErrorDocument 403 /pagenotfound.php

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ viewgames.php?search=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ viewgames.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^users/(.*)$ users.php?action=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^play/(.*)/$ play.php?gn=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^play/(.*)$ play.php?gn=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

I have a script called `play.php` which is rewrited using .htaccess to `/play/` i.e if someone requests `example.com/play/foobar`, the request will be sent to `example.com/play.php?gn=foobar`.

I'm very new to .htaccess. I will really appreciate your help.

*[Edit]* I have updated the above code to show my full .htaccess. I hope it helps. BTW, the stars (*) on the first line of code is to hide my actual website address.

Comment: Just to properly understand the issue, why would you need this?

Comment: My website loads several games under an iframe. Some games cannot run on HTTPS, and cause mixed content issues. To prevent those issues, I want to disable HTTPS on that specific page. Didn't you notice that some popular gaming sites don't enable HTTPS?

Comment: _"Didn't you notice that some popular gaming sites don't enable HTTPS?"_ - I don't visit gaming sites so... no.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson http://www.silvergames.com/en/stabbyio this game doesn't support HTTPS, so they disabled it. Then again, https://www.silvergames.com/en/deadwalk-io supports HTTPS, so they didn't remove HTTPS from this gameplay page.

Comment: You should either use a proxy with TLS or tell the game provider about letsencrypt, https://letsencrypt.org. Free certificate(s).

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess in question?

Comment: @anubhava I've updated the post and included my whole .htaccess. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is full .htaccess with my comments:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*********"

ErrorDocument 404 /pagenotfound.php
ErrorDocument 403 /pagenotfound.php

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# it is important to keep www removal rule as first rule to avoid multiple redirects
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# http->https if URL is not starting with /play/ or /play.php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule !^play(?:\.php|/.*)?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE,NC]

# https->http if URL is starting with /play/
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^play(?:/.*)?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE,NC]

RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ viewgames.php?search=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ viewgames.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^users/(.*)$ users.php?action=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^play/(.+?)/?$ play.php?gn=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# make sure to check for presence of .php file before rewrite
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

It is important to completely clear browser cache or use a new browser of testing the changes.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your code works like a charm. But I am encountering a simple problem: When I access https://example.com/play/blabla, it redirects to http://example.com/play.php?gn=blabla. Is there any way to redirect to the clean URL? or will it always be like this?

Comment: exactly what I meant :-). The HTTP and HTTPS can change, but I really need the clean URL to remain cleaned.

Comment: after I uploaded the new code, the HTTP change does not occur anymore, i.e http://example.com/ does change to https://example.com, but https://example.com/play/blabla doesn't change to http://example.com/play/blabla

Comment: I've edited the question again to show exactly how I need the site URL to behave. Please help.

Comment: Got it, test my changes in a new browser again

Comment: thank you SO much!! I couldn't solve this problem after searching for a straight week, and you did it for me. I'm rewarding the bounty to you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable `https` to your `play.php` URI using the following `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond ℅{REQUEST_URI} play\.php$ [OR]
RewriteCond ℅{REQUEST_URI} /play
RewriteCond ℅{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://℅{HTTP_HOST}℅{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R]
```

This will redirect `https://example.com/play.php` to its non SSL version. 
Since your rule already checks `http` urls , you can also add a condition to your rule to exclude the `play.php` from HTTPS redirection something like the following :

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 #redirect all to https except /play and /play.php 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !play
 RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Your code does work when I call https://example.com/play.php?gn=xyz, but doesn't on a clean URL https://example.com/play/xyz. As I mentioned in my original post, I really need the code for the clean URL

Comment: @SayanjyotiDas I have updated the Rules. This should now handle both URIs `play` and `play.php` . Please clear your browser cache before testing this updated code.